# Graph with distinct automorphisms but no fixed-point free automorphism

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

Does there exist a graph $G = \{ V, E \}$ with the following properties:

- for every node $v_i \in V$ there is an automorphism $\varphi$ for which $\varphi(v_i) \neq v_i$
- $G$ has no fixed-point-free automorphism (i.e. an automorphism $\varphi'$ in which for all $i$ $\varphi'(v_i) \neq v_i$)

If the answer is yes is there a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... this seems a good example: at least one automorphism for each vertex such that $\varphi(v_i) \neq v_i$, but no FPF automorphism:

[image: Counterexample 9FCDB7A13F73E9B27A8802D33AFDEA09]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it always has a FPF automorphism and therefore, GI is polynomial equivalent to FPF automorphism (a NP complete problem). In fact, I have 2 distinct proofs to the statement above.

Comment: Could you share the proofs?

Comment: :-) ... indeed I saw your [proof](https://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~chauhain/GI%20is%20in%20NP%20complete.pdf), the only weak point is the induction step of the theorem (which is not so clear to be honest), so I asked here if there is a *simple* counterexample ...

Comment: I really really appreciate that you looked at the paper. I hate giving excuse but, I am not in the position which I can write a formal proof easily. I am an uneducated student - I had straight Fs and dropped out of college 3 years ago and only returned few months ago, I only encountered this problem recently and I have bigger problem with English and Latex barrier than actually solving the problem.  But I can bet my life on this matter that it is actually correct.

Comment: @nhc: don't worry, after seeing it on cstheory (I didn't downvote it ;-) I gave it a look and tried to find a counterexample, but didn't find it quickly; now I have a few minutes and I'm trying again. BTW don't bet anything :-D ... one of the first lessons I learned in these sites is that there are many smart people out there ... and most of them are smarter than me :-)

Comment: @nhc: I posted a counterexample ... see if it's ok.

Comment: I will redraw it so that it will be come clearer. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: @nhc: ... be aware that a FPF isomorphism must preserve adjacency ... so try to find a FPF automorphism of the first graph on the left (the others, on the right, show the only two options you have if upper node moves ... and it must move in a FPF automorphism)

Comment: To my shame, your counter example is a beautiful one. Really appreciate that you found it, I was so sure of my logic that I didnt even think that it was possible.

Comment: @nhc: I didn't found it by myself: I found a picture of the gadget used in the original NPC proof of FPF authomorphism (the paper is beyond paywall and I don't have access to it) and just noticed that it satisfies the requirements. BTW don't give up: if you enjoy Theoretical-CS then keep learning and trying  ... soon or later you'll find something interesting ;-)